# About asymptotic behaviour of a divergent integral.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, asymptotics, laurent-series

I have the function $f(x) = x \tanh(\pi x) \log (x^2 +a^2)$ where $a$ is some positive real number. For the logarithm I am assuming a branch-cut along the positive imaginary axis starting at $x = ia$. So the branching effect on the "log" is that its imaginary part is $\pi$ on the right and above the point $ai$ on the positive imaginary axis and $-\pi$ on the left and above.

I wanted to understand how the value of the integral of this function behaves when $x$ is integrated from $0$ to $A >0$. Using the parity symmetry of the function I extended it on a semi-circle in the upper half plane of radius $A$ about the origin.

Then I did a large $A$ expansion ("Series" about $A=\infty$ on Mathematica) and found that $xf(x)$ (that would practically be the integrand when converted into a $\phi$ integral with $x = Ae^{i\phi}$), this function asymptotes as, $e^{2i\phi} \log(e^{2i\phi})A^2 + 2A^2 \log(A) + a^2$ (+ terms which go to zero as $A$ goes to infinity). Now on this asymptotic form the $\phi$ is integrable from $0$ to $\pi$ giving a finite answer.

- So relying on this *Mathematica* result can I say that this integral therefore diverges in the large $A$ limit as $ \text{(number)} A^2 + \text{(number)} A^2 \log(A)$ ?
- Further I chose $a=2$ and it seems to me that on using "NIntegrate" Mathematica says that the integral of this function on a circle centered at $2i$ goes to zero as the radius goes to 0.

Is this correct?

Thinking analytically this seems to be right - if one does a small radius expansion of integrand about the branch point $2i$ then the integrand smoothly goes to $0$ in the small radius limit. One might fear that the small radius limit does not commute with the integral - to check that I also plotted the value of the numerical integration of the function around this circle as a function of the radius - and the graph does seem to go to zero smoothly in the zero radius limit.

In doing the above *Mathematica* based checking I am trusting that Mathematica knows how to contour integrate a function around its branch-cut. Though thinking analytically I get that while going around the point $2i$ the function needs to be modified as follows (to fit with the branching convention stated earlier at the top) - that for $0 < \phi = \arg(z - 2i = \epsilon e^{i \phi}) < \frac{\pi}{2}$ one adds a $-\frac{i3\pi}{2}$ to the $\log (z^2 + 4)$ and add a $\frac{i\pi}{2}$ for $\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \phi  \leq 2\pi$.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  Are you interested in obtaining the asymptotic behavior of $\int_0^A x \tanh(\pi x) \log(x^2+a^2)\,dx$ as $A \to \infty$ with $A > 0$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Yes!

Comment: Ok, I've posted an answer.  I don't see how contour integration and branch points are relevant to that question so let me know if I've misunderstood something from your post.

Answer (score 3):

You're interested in the asymptotic behavior of

$$
\begin{align}
I_a(A) &= \int_0^A x \tanh(\pi x) \log(x^2+a^2)\,dx \\
&= \int_1^A x \tanh(\pi x) \log(x^2+a^2)\,dx + \int_0^1 x \tanh(\pi x) \log(x^2+a^2)\,dx \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

as $A \to \infty$.  Let's rewrite the integrand as

$$
\begin{align}
&x \tanh(\pi x) \log(x^2+a^2) \\
&\qquad = x \log(x^2+a^2) + x \log(x^2+a^2) \Bigl(\tanh(\pi x) - 1\Bigr) \\
&\qquad = x\log(x^2) + x\log(1+a^2/x^2) + x \log(x^2+a^2) \Bigl(\tanh(\pi x) - 1\Bigr). \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Now

$$
|\tanh(\pi x) - 1| = \frac{2}{1+e^{2\pi x}} \leq 2e^{-2\pi x} = O(e^{-2\pi x}) \qquad \text{as } x \to \infty, \tag{3}
$$

$$
\log(x^2 + a^2) = O(x) \qquad \text{as } x \to \infty, \tag{4}
$$

and

$$
\log(1+a^2/x^2) = \frac{a^2}{x^2} + O(x^{-4}) \qquad \text{as } x \to \infty, \tag{5}
$$

so using $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$ in $(2)$ we have

$$
\begin{align}
x \tanh(\pi x) \log(x^2+a^2) &= x\log(x^2) + \frac{a^2}{x} + O(x^{-3}) + O(x^2 e^{-2\pi x}) \\
&= 2x\log x + \frac{a^2}{x} + O(x^{-3})
\end{align}
$$

as $x \to \infty$.  Therefore, if we write

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_1^A x \tanh(\pi x) \log(x^2+a^2)\,dx \\
&\qquad = \int_1^A \left(2x\log x + \frac{a^2}{x}\right)\,dx + \int_1^A \left(x\tanh(\pi x)\log(x^2+a^2) - 2x\log x - \frac{a^2}{x}\right)\,dx,
\end{align}
$$
$$
\tag{6}
$$

then the last integral converges as $A \to \infty$, and the second to last integral is

$$
\int_1^A \left(2x\log x + \frac{a^2}{x}\right)\,dx = A^2 \log A - \frac{1}{2}A^2 + a^2 \log A + \frac{1}{2}. \tag{7}
$$

Thus, defining

$$
\begin{align}
C(a) = &\frac{1}{2} + \int_1^\infty \left(x\tanh(\pi x)\log(x^2+a^2) - 2x\log x - \frac{a^2}{x}\right)\,dx \\&\qquad + \int_0^1 x \tanh(\pi x) \log(x^2+a^2)\,dx
\end{align}
$$

and combining $(1)$, $(6)$, and $(7)$ we get

> $$
> I_a(A) = A^2 \log A - \frac{1}{2}A^2 + a^2 \log A + C(a) + \epsilon_a(A),
> $$
>   where $\epsilon_a(A) \to 0$ as $A \to \infty$ for fixed $a \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for your insights - but I really wanted to understand it in the complex integral form because in this picture its not clear how the value of the integral depends on "a" - which I believe it does - this way of writing the integral makes it a priori feel as if $C(a)$ depends on "a^2" but probably it depends on "a". So to understand how $C(a)$ would change if the sign of a is changed is hard unless one can explicitly do the integrals in $C(a)$.

Comment: [...also any thoughts why the coefficients of "A^2 log(A)" and "A^2" are not matching with my argument for getting those terms? .. wonder my argument misses this extra "Log A" term that you see...]

Comment: $C(a)$ definitely only depends on $a^2$; it's right there in the formula :).  The original integral $\int_0^A x \tanh(\pi x) \log(x^2+a^2)\,dx$ depends on $a^2$ (not on $a$), so everything afterwards will only depend on $a^2$ too.  As for the coefficients, I don't really understand your argument, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: Let me think about this $a^2$ dependence of $C(a)$ a bit more - there are various other reasons (given the physical source of this question!) as to why $C$ should have probably depended on $a$ and not $a^2$. BUT, my one try at an asymptotic argument was like if you think of this as a complex function  $z Tanh (\pi z) Log (z^2 + a^2)$ and try integrating it on a $A$ radius semicircle (centered at the origin) over the UHP - now substitute $z = A e^{i\phi}$ and find the large $A$ asymptotics of it (using "Series" on Mathematica about $A = \infty$)

Comment: Then one sees that this series expansion has two terms which diverge in the $A$ going to $\infty$ limit and those terms are $A^2Log(A)$ and $A^2$ (and there is a constant). Now one can integrate the $\phi$ dependence of these coefficients from $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi$ - for these functions of $\phi$ there is no branchcut in the UHP  - is this argument right? [...this doesn't get the extra $log(A)$ term that you are getting...]

Comment: I wonder if there is any issue starting in your asymptotics proclaimed for $log (x^2 + a^2)$ - for which Mathematica claims that the asymptotics about x = infinity is $ 2Log[x] + (a/x)^2 + O(1/x^3) $ - which is not the same as yours...

Comment: Are you referring to my assertion that $\log(x^2+a^2) = O(x)$?  That's true simply because $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x^2+a^2)}{x} = 0.$$  I didn't need anything more precise for its application (the third term in the last line of $(2)$)

Comment: Is my argument correct? Infact now I see that by my argument the coefficient of $A^2 Log [A]$ is infact $2i e^{2 i \phi }$ (and the integral of this coefficient from $\phi = 0 $ to $\pi$ is 0) SO the divergence is only $A^2$...

Comment: I still can't fathom your argument, and parts of it seem to rely on Mathematica, so I can't really comment on its correctness.  But to start, how do you relate an integral on a positive ray $[0,A]$ to one on a half circle in the upper half plane?  Perhaps you could draw a picture to illustrate?

Comment: See this problem - I put in this command into Mathematica, "Plot [ ( NIntegrate [ 
    x Tanh [ \[Pi] x] Log [ x^2 + 1]  , {x, 0, A}] ) - ( 
   A^2 Log [A] - (A^2/2 ) + Log [A]  ) , {A, 10000, 100000}]"

Comment: By your argument this graph should have been asymptoting to a constant (C(1)) - but it doesn't.

Comment: Without proper supervision Mathematica will often return erroneous results.  The Plot command can be finicky, so try some numbers individually.  For example, `a=1;A=10000;NIntegrate[x Tanh[Pi x] Log[x^2+a^2],{x,0,A},WorkingPrecision->30]-A^2 Log[A]+1/2 A^2-a^2 Log[A]` and afterwards `a=1;A=100000;NIntegrate[x Tanh[Pi x] Log[x^2+a^2],{x,0,A},WorkingPrecision->30]-A^2 Log[A]+1/2 A^2-a^2 Log[A]`

Comment: Using the Plot command with the required precision seems to take forever, so you could sample fewer points using a command like `a=1;ListPlot[Table[{A,NIntegrate[x Tanh[Pi x] Log[x^2+a^2],{x,0,A},WorkingPrecision->30]-A^2 Log[A]+1/2 A^2-a^2 Log[A]},{A,10000,100000,5000}],Joined->True,PlotRange->All,AxesOrigin->{10000,Automatic}]`.  Here's the graph this generates: http://i.stack.imgur.com/w0JgA.png

Comment: Thanks! As I said - this answer is kind of bit different from what I am looking for - for various reasons I would have loved to see the finite part depend on "a" and not "a^2" - but that is not coming here - like if you replaced the log term by 1/(x^2 +a^2) then thats what would happen.

Comment: Any thoughts on the complex analytic version? I am thinking - does the answer depend on whether the semi-circle is closed in the UHP or in the LHP - of course its not just a semi-circle - it has to have a key-hole contour about the branch-points ( $\pm ia$ depending on the U/LHP) and a semi-circular hump around each pole (at i (n + 1/2) and n is positive or negative integer depending on whether its the U/LHP) on each side and then take the limit of each hump and the hole going to zero - right?

Comment: I guess that in the limit each hump will just produce just the residue at each point - right? Or is there any more subtlety here? I guess the usual "Residue" function on Mathematica does give the right answer!

Comment: Again, if the integral you start with only depends on $|a|$ (like the one you asked about) then everything that follows can only depend on $|a|$.  It really is as simple as that.  What is your integral when $a = 5$?  What is your integral when $a = -5$?  Are they the same?  Then how could the two integrals have different asymptotic expansions?

Comment: It isn't that simple - like I said consider the integral $\int _0 ^A x tanh (\pi x) \frac{1}{x^2 + a^2}$ - the value of this integral depends on $mod(a)$ and not just on $a^2$ - this wasn't obvious to me till a lot of effort - I would have hoped for a similar thing here.

Comment: Huh?? Depending on $|a|$ (what you mean by $\operatorname{mod}(a)$ I assume) is the same thing as depending on $a^2$ since $|a| = \sqrt{a^2}$ and $a^2 = |a|^2$.  The integral literally doesn't change if you replace $a$ with $-a$.

Comment: If the function depends on mod(a) then the function is non-analytically depended on the value of a and that is quite different than a simple dependency on a^2. There are other examples also - like $\sum _{n \in \mathbb{Z}} log (n^2 + a^2)$ depends on mod(a) and NOT on $a^2$ and this leads to non-trivial physics effects. (....i wonder if you not being aware of the physics origins of the situation is causing the confusion...) (BTW this infinite sum example uses Riemann zeta-function regularization)

Comment: Wait a minute, I think it just clicked for me.  You mentioned zeta regularization in your last comment -- are you considering $C(a)$ to be a regularization of $\int_0^\infty x\tanh(\pi x)\log(x^2+a^2)\,dx$?  If so then it totally makes sense why you'd be interested in analyticity with respect to $a$.  Sorry if I've been a little dense this whole time.  I'm happy to look at this further if you'd like.  Please send me an email at the address listed on my website [here](http://mathstat.dal.ca/~antoniov/) so we can continue this discussion there.

Comment: Thanks! I will I guess email you sometime! May be you can help in this other question I asked related to my complex analytic viewpoint of this integral, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736038/about-the-branch-cut-in-the-complex-logarithm